# How do I line up two elements horizontally with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've looked at other answers on this site but I haven't been able to find a working solution. My situation is a little strange in the way that I shouldn't change the html code, I should avoid using classes where possible and I can't use ids.

So the html I have looks like this

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #dddddd, #f7f8ff, #ffffff);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: "faricy-new-web", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  background-color: #A9B6C7;
  margin: 5% 10% 5% 35%;
  padding: 2%;
  display: block;
}


/*TITLE BOX STYLE*/

.title div {
  display: flex;
}

.title .c4title {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.title p .c6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <p class="c4title">
    <a name="h.c2v2rn37qt4d"></a><span>Title</span></p>
  <div>
    <p class="c1"><span></span></p>
    <p class="c6"><span>Info: <pre>Result</pre></span></p>
    <p class="c6"><span>Date: <pre>Wed Jun 21 2017</pre></span></p>
    <p class="c1"><span></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this but I can't seem to get it to align properly.

[image: I want it to look like this but I can't seem to get it to align properly.]

So my question is is there a way to do this with these conditions or do I have to go change up the html?

Edit: Ok, so if I remove "display: flex" from the .title div then floats work fine but Is there a way to do the same thing with flexboxes?

Comment: Hello, 

Just for your information, 
`<pre>` element is a Flow content and is not allowed in `<p>` wich only accept Phrasing content.
If you check the html output of your code, you get `<p class="c6"><span>Info: </span></p><pre>Result</pre><p></p>`

Comment: That is new information to me, thanks. I can't really change the code much though so if it;s functionally <p class="c6"><span>Info: </span></p><pre>Result</pre><p></p> do I have to change it?

Comment: can you use js/jquery to manipulate content?

Comment: I'm not allowed.

Comment: You can learn more about Phrasing content through [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #dddddd, #f7f8ff, #ffffff);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: "faricy-new-web", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  background-color: #A9B6C7;
  margin: 5% 10% 5% 35%;
  padding: 2%;
  display: block;
}


/*TITLE BOX STYLE*/

.title div {
  
}

.title .c4title {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.c6 {
  float:left;  
  margin: 0;
}

pre{
margin:0;
text-align:left;
}

.c1{float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <p class="c4title">
    <a name="h.c2v2rn37qt4d"></a><span>Title</span></p>
  <div>
    <p class="c1"><span></span></p>
    <p class="c6"><span>Info: <pre>Result</pre></span></p>
    <p class="c6"><span>Date: <pre>Wed Jun 21 2017</pre></span></p>
    <p class="c1"><span></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works and I'm going to use it in place of flex boxes for now.

Comment: k glad to help.! using flex-box float will not work.

Comment: I only noticed when you had it taken out of your code, which I am incredibly glad to know now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use float:left or float:right on your elements. 
Or use relative position, and play with the offsets. 
For example: 50 px to the left

Comment: Yes, of course. Include float:left; to all the elements you wish to align. Check this video out, it shows you what floats do:  https://youtu.be/VwxGKpvW8Zk